# How would you detect the current browser in an Api Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to detect the current web browser within one of my Api Controllers in my program using MVC4.  Everywhere I look people say to use `Request.Browser`, however I can't get that to work.  Any suggestions or is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: Request in an APIController is an HttpRequestMessage vs the HttpRequest that contains the browser information.  To get the browser capabilities, just use `HttpBrowserCapabilities bc = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the HttpBrowserCapabilities in System.Web like this

```
        var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;
        var userBrowser = new HttpBrowserCapabilities { Capabilities = new Hashtable { { string.Empty, userAgent } } };
        var factory = new BrowserCapabilitiesFactory();
        factory.ConfigureBrowserCapabilities(new NameValueCollection(), userBrowser);

        //Set User browser Properties
        BrowserBrand = userBrowser.Browser;
        BrowserVersion = userBrowser.Version;
```

This relies on browscap.ini in Windows/System32/inetsrv/ or Windows/SysWOW64/inetsrv for definitions.

This article may also help - http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/03/05/use-asp-net-4-browser-definitions-with-asp-net-3-5

Comment: If you use HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent, why not use HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser?

Comment: @PeterHedberg Good question, but I tried your solution and found that UserAgent contains all supported browsers and OS as well. But if I tried with MS Edge, the HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser show me that I am using Chrome.

Comment: @Kramer MS Edge is on Chromium now. https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/12/06/microsoft-edge-making-the-web-better-through-more-open-source-collaboration/

Answer (score 10):

You could do something like following too from within the Web API's action:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage currentRequest = this.Request;
System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderValueCollection<System.Net.Http.Headers.ProductInfoHeaderValue> userAgentHeader = currentRequest.Headers.UserAgent;
```