# ASP.NET Web Api - How to Detect if Request is from Mobile in ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an old Controller class in my company which inherits `ApiController`.

One of the actions are a `POST` endpoint that receives data from browser.

Since I'm in the `ApiController`, I don't have the built-in property `IsMobile` to detect.

So, How do I Detect if Request is from Mobile in `ApiController` ?

Any alternatives to suggests ?

Answer (score 2):

You might look at the User-Agent header, and look for *hints* of mobile client:

```
var userAgent = Request.Headers.UserAgent.ToString();
```

You might be able to look for certain strings like 'mobile' or 'mobi' (or search for multiple alternative keywords).

Here's a page that lists mobile client user agents:
https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/hardware_type_specific/mobile/7

**Update:**

Here's a library that's already doing something similar with the user-agent header:
https://github.com/wangkanai/Detection

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the initial answers, the key is using `UserAgent`.
I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17306139/11995160) which I wrapped up in an `ActionFilter` in case I would like to use it thou out multiple actions

```
/// <summary>
/// This action filter sets Request's properties with a "BrowserCapabilitiesFactory" object. <br/>
/// To get it, use <b>Request.Properties.TryGetValue("UserBrowser", out yourObjectToSet);</b>. <br/>
/// With that, you can check browser details of the request. Use this for <b>ApiController</b> actions. <br/>
/// If browser was not found or any exception occured in filter, then the value of the key will be set to null, 
/// By doing that , ensures that the Properties will always have a key-value of UserBrowser
/// </summary>
public class GetUserBrowserActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        try
        {
            // ============================== Get User agent and parse it to a strongly type object ============================== //
            var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;
            var userBrowser = new HttpBrowserCapabilities { Capabilities = new Hashtable { { string.Empty, userAgent } } };
            var factory = new BrowserCapabilitiesFactory();
            factory.ConfigureBrowserCapabilities(new NameValueCollection(), userBrowser);
            actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("UserBrowser", userBrowser);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("UserBrowser", null);
        }

    }
}
```